# Regular Expression using R Programming Language

Tags: r, regex

```
String<- "46,XX,t(1;19)(p32;q13.3),t(6;9)(p22;q34),del(32)t(12;16)(p12;q21)[cp20]"
```

The value I want to extract is `t(1;19)(p32;q13.3), t(6;9)(p22;q34), t(12;16)(p12;q21)`

The regex I'm using

```
ABC<-str_extract(String, regex("t.{1,16}"))
```

output I Get: `t(1;19)(p32;q13.3`

I know my code I incomplete but I'm unable to figure out a way to extract this information.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `String` is :

```
String<- "46,XX,t(1;19)(p32;q13.3),t(6;9)(p22;q34),del(32)t(12;16)(p12;q21)[cp20]"
```

We can use `str_extract_all` as :

```
stringr::str_extract_all(String, "t\\(.*?\\)\\(.*?\\)")[[1]]
#[1] "t(1;19)(p32;q13.3)" "t(6;9)(p22;q34)"    "t(12;16)(p12;q21)"
```

This returns `"t"` followed by everything in round brackets (`()`), followed by everything in another round bracket next to it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I forgot to add Quotes to my original post, variable String is one complete string.

Comment: Can ask you what does the [[1]] at the end of the expression do? It works perfectly without it.

Comment: `str_extract_all` returns a list of length 1. Using `[[1]]`, we get output as a character vector.

Comment: instead of the string i have a variable, with your solution the output i get is [[342]]
[1] "t(9;11)(p22;q23)"  stacked one upon each other. I want to transform this regix into a new variable. Sorry if I'm bothering you. Thanks

Comment: You probably need `unlist` then : `unlist(stringr::str_extract_all(String, "t\\(.*?\\)\\(.*?\\)"))`.